# How to identify the nth instance of a value in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame projection.hitters composed of ~5000 observances:

```
> head(projection.hitters)
                Name Positions  points PAR
223   Miguel Cabrera        3B 1007.97  NA
227       Mike Trout        OF  962.63  NA
160       Joey Votto        1B  863.27  NA
244 Paul Goldschmidt        1B  841.83  NA
256       Ryan Braun        OF  825.67  NA
28  Andrew McCutchen        OF  823.67  NA
```

Suppose I want to find the nth best instance of where Positions==1B by points and designate that row with a PAR value of 0.  All other 1B would have PAR values defined by the difference between their "points" values above or below the number of points where PAR==0 of that nth 1B.

For example, if the nth 1B were Paul Goldschmidt, his PAR==0 and Joey Votto would have a PAR==21.44, the difference between the two points values.

This will be done for each position.

EDIT:
I will need to identify a different nth instance for each position, e.g. the 12th best 1B and 80th best OF.

Comment: Oh rats: I missed this-- do you want the n-th row for each position, or do you actually want the n-th highest (or lowest) point value for each position?  Your title and text are ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity.  I am looking for the nth row of each position, but n will change depending on the position.  I added an edit to try to add clarity.

Comment: But your edit says "12th best..." while your comment said "nth row for that position" . So unless your dataframe is already ordered by `points` those aren't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this with `plyr`

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text="Name Positions  points PAR
Miguel Cabrera        3B 1007.97  NA
Mike Trout        OF  962.63  NA
Joey Votto        1B  863.27  NA
Paul Goldschmidt        1B  841.83  NA
Ryan Braun        OF  825.67  NA
Andrew McCutchen        OF  823.67  NA")

n<-1  #instance

require(plyr)
ddply(df,.(Positions),mutate,PAR=abs(points-points[n]))

#         Name Positions  points    PAR
#1       Votto        1B  863.27   0.00
#2 Goldschmidt        1B  841.83  21.44
#3     Cabrera        3B 1007.97   0.00
#4       Trout        OF  962.63   0.00
#5       Braun        OF  825.67 136.96
#6   McCutchen        OF  823.67 138.96
```

**EDIT UPDATED TO VARY n PER POSITION**

```
n<-matrix(c(1,1,2),ncol=1,dimnames=list(unique(df$Positions))) # first, first and second instance of player per positions

require(plyr)
ddply(df,.(Positions),mutate,PAR=abs(points-points[n[Positions]]))

Name Positions  points    PAR
1       Votto        1B  863.27   0.00
2 Goldschmidt        1B  841.83  21.44
3     Cabrera        3B 1007.97   0.00
4       Trout        OF  962.63 136.96
5       Braun        OF  825.67   0.00
6   McCutchen        OF  823.67   2.00
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for, thank you.  What if I want to specify a different "n" for each position? E.g. Suppose I want the 12th best 1B but 80th best OF?

Comment: Updated in the example - just make n a vector

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(projection.hitters, PAR = ave(points, Positions, 
                                        FUN = function(x) x - min(x)))

                Name Positions  points    PAR
223   Miguel Cabrera        3B 1007.97   0.00
227       Mike Trout        OF  962.63 138.96
160       Joey Votto        1B  863.27  21.44
244 Paul Goldschmidt        1B  841.83   0.00
256       Ryan Braun        OF  825.67   2.00
28  Andrew McCutchen        OF  823.67   0.00
```

Comment: ?This solves part of the problem, but how does one specify the `nth` best?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little easier to do in dplyr because it provides the `nth` function to extract the nth value (either in the original row order, or ordered by another variable)

```
df <- read.csv(text =
"name,position,points
Miguel Cabrera,3B,1007.97
Mike Trout,OF,962.63
Joey Votto,1B,863.27
Paul Goldschmidt,1B,841.83
Ryan Braun,OF,825.67
Andrew McCutchen,OF,823.67", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df %.% 
  group_by(position) %.%
  mutate(
    offset = nth(points, 1, order_by = points), 
    delta = points - offset
  )
```

If you want to look for a different value according to the `position`, I'd create a named vector and use that to generate the position to use:

```
nth <- c("OF" = 3, "3B" = 1, "1B" = 2)
df %.% 
  group_by(position) %.%
  mutate(
    pos = nth[position],
    offset = nth(points, pos[1], order_by = points), 
    delta = points - offset
  )
```